# seg fault showing even after program execution

Tags: c, buffer, segmentation-fault

---

I just wrote a simple program for `buffer overflow inspection`.

---

This is simple code for buffer overflow saved to `buffer.c`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int pass(char password[])
{
  int auth=0;
  char p[16];
  strcpy(p,password);
  if(strcmp(p,"Hello")==0)
  {
    auth=1;
  }
  return auth;
}
void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  if(pass(argv[1]))
  {
    printf("----ACCESS GRANTED----\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("----ACCESS DENIED----\n");
  }
}
//aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
// aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Upon running this, the result shows:

```
 gcc -g buffer.c
 ./a.out Hello
----ACCESS GRANTED----
```

(This was expected.)

```
 ./a.out aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
----ACCESS GRANTED----
```

(Indicating the overflow.)

```
  ./a.out aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
----ACCESS GRANTED----
Segmentation fault
```

I wonder why saying segmentation fault after showing the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be assuming that the segfault happens *after* the program terminated. It actually happens during execution, most likely while executing the implicit return statement at the end of the main function.

When running a C program, the system does a bit of initialization before calling the main function (typically, the actual entry point is a `_start()` function and `_start()` calls `main()`). Internally, calling the `main()` function saves the return address (the address to return to when the function is over). This is obviously dependent on the CPU and compiler, but the return address is often saved on the stack, next to the array `p`. When doing a buffer overflow on `p`, you may overwrite the return address, hence things go wrong when `main()` tries to return. Most likely the program will branch to an address which doesn't exist or is not executable.

Note that an attacker could exploit this kind of bug to try to jump to a given location and execute a piece of code that wasn't supposed to be executed.

Comment: The funny thing is why it doesn't crash when trying to return from  `pass()`.

Comment: This totally depends on the compiler and operating system. On OpenBSD, you'll get an "Abort trap (core dumped)" when it overflows the buffer (immediately), and you certainly never get "Access granted" with a string of `a`s

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the string that the user supplied on the command line to a buffer that is too short, which means *anything* could happen.  In this case, you don't need to copy the string at all as you can run `strcmp()` on the `password` string directly.

E.g.

```
checkpass(char *password)
{
    return !strcmp(password, "Hello");
}
```

(this assumes that `password` is a nul-terminated string)

Comment: But that would remove the buffer overflow :)